# Is it possible to access fragment's UI elements from activitiy's onCreate

Tags: android, android-fragments

As the headline says: Is it possible to get the currently visible fragment with all UI elements initialized within the onCreate() method of the activity?
I am implementing a separation into model, view and controller with separate controller classes that handle business logic and UI events. Therefore they need a reference to the current fragment. These controllers are initialized in the onCreate() method of the activity hence I need the initialized fragment within that method.

I welcome any kind of advice :)

EDIT:

Adding some code for better understanding: 
I'm using dagger for dependency injection and would like to do this in the onCreate() method. As I said before my controller needs an the mapView element. And that is why I would like to have a fragment with the mapView element initialized.

MapActivity#onCreate(Bundle):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

    MyMapFragment fragment = new MyMapFragment();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.activity_container, fragment, "fragment")
        .commit();

    ObjectGraph.create(new Module(fragment.getMapView())).inject(this);
}
```

activity_layout.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_container"
        ... />
    <ListView .../>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

fragment_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <org.osmdroid.map.MapView 
        android:id"@+id/mapview"
        ... />
    <Button .../>
</RelativeLayout>
```

2ND EDIT:
So it seems like that is not possible... Yay for the downvote ^^

Comment: What you wanna do isn't possible. Check the lifecycle of Fragments and Activity again.

Comment: There is only few information on how the lifecycles of fragments and activities interact so I thought that the onCreateView() would get called right when the fragment is created...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, no. At the time activity `onCreate()` runs, the fragment is not attached to the activity yet.

Right place to access a fragment's views is in the fragment itself. Consider putting the controller assignments in the fragment within its lifecycle such as `onCreateView()` or `onViewCreated()`.

It is possible to explicitly run queued up fragment transactions using  [`executePendingTransactions()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#executePendingTransactions%28%29), or implicitly after `super.onStart()` has been run in the activity lifecycle. After that the fragment views are accessible in the activity view hierarchy.

Comment: Cannot do this in the fragment as the activity is the starting point of the injection... I thought that there is another option than to use a callback from the fragment. That seems to be a clumsy solution to me...

Answer (score -1):

in your `onCreate` method add the following (I used a textview as an example):

```
while (fragment.getView() == null) {

        }
rootView = fragment.getView();
TextView myView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
```

Make sure to return the `rootView` in your fragment's `onCreateView` method as follows:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activity,
                container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
```

I know that the idea of getting your fragment to access its views from the main activity is bad. Yet, this solution may give you what you want.

Comment: This will block the UI thread forever and the app is killed with "app not responding".

Comment: @laalto I think it will stay in the while loop for a while until the activity receives the fragment `rootView`. It won't block the app for ever.
I don't know if you mean that returning the rootView from the fragment is not guaranteed. What's you opinion?

Comment: The fragment transactions would be executed on the same UI thread you're blocking.

Comment: The view will not be created as Android runs on one thread only. You would block that Thread forever