# findViewById in nested Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I am trying to display results of Activity processing in a fragment (R.layout.fragment_2_ble) instead of the main activity layout (R.layout.activity_main).

Thus, I have a problem when I am trying to find the (R.id.devicelist) which is in fragment_2_ble and not in activity_main.

MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    //setButtonText();

    ble_device_list_adapter = new ListAdapter();

    ListView listView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.deviceList);
    listView.setAdapter(ble_device_list_adapter);

    ble_scanner = new BLEScanner();

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            if (ble_scanning) {
                ble_scanner.stopScanning();
            }

            BluetoothDevice device = ble_device_list_adapter.getDevice(position);
            if (toast != null) {
                toast.cancel();
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PeripheralControlActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(PeripheralControlActivity.EXTRA_NAME, device.getName());
            intent.putExtra(PeripheralControlActivity.EXTRA_ID, device.getAddress());
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    displaySelectedScreen(R.id.nav_data);

    //ButterKnife.bind(this);
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean logged = prefs.getBoolean("logged", false);
    if (!logged) {
        //Launch login activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

private void displaySelectedScreen(int itemId) {

    //creating fragment object
    Fragment fragment = null;

    //initializing the fragment object which is selected
    switch (itemId) {
        case R.id.nav_data:
            fragment = new DataFragment();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_BLE:
            fragment = new BLEFragment();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_settings:
            fragment = new SettingsFragment();
            break;
    }

    //replacing the fragment
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}


@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    displaySelectedScreen(item.getItemId());
    return true;
}
```

BLEFragment.java:

```
public class BLEFragment extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //returning our layout file
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_2_ble, container, false);
}
```

Any idea on how to fix this ?

Comment: Why you wanna get ListView in Activity when you have it in fragment? Deal with it in fragment instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have missing concepts about fragments.
If the listView is in the fragment, you should make the findViewById and set OnClickListener in the fragment. Just like this:

```
public class BLEFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //returning our layout file
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_2_ble, container, false);
        ListView list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.your_id);
        list.setOnClickListenre(...);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your fragments `onCreateView()` you will have something like this:

```
YOURLISTVIEW = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.deviceList);
```

Inside of your fragment you could create a method like this:

```
public ListView getListView(){
    return YOURLISTVIEW;
}
```

Then in main you would have an instance of your fragment.

You can access the `ListView` from the fragment.

```
myFragment.getListView();
```

I will add that if this activity is the parent of the fragment, that `findViewById(R.id.fragmentITEM)` should work.

Answer (score 0):

By default you can't achieve this kind of structure. You can't find fragment UI elements in activity on create.

Becoz fragment UI element not created when onCreate view created in activity.

you can find brief answer in this link : [Is it possible to access fragment's UI elements from activitiy's onCreate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24199788/is-it-possible-to-access-fragments-ui-elements-from-activitiys-oncreate)